# how can we route the path using angular stateprovider?

Tags: angularjs, state, angular-ui-router

Here I am trying to route the path by using this code. but unable to catch the url like :

1. **warranty**
2. **warranty/1234**

state:

```
 $stateProvider.state('warrantyid',{
            url:'/warranty/:id',                                
            views:{
                'staticpage' : {                    
                templateUrl:'template/warrantytpl.php',
                controller:'warrantyController'                     
            } }

        });
```

Only I am able to get the url like this **warranty1234**, if I tried like the url (url:'/warranty:id') in stateProvider. I have tried number of methods but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/L6vAe7ninidWsn57IGPR?p=preview)

Just use configuration **`params : {}`** and setting **`squash`**

```
.state('warrantyid',{
    url:'/warranty/:id',                                
    params: {id : { squash: true}}, // here we omit id if not passed
    views:{
        'staticpage' : {                    
        templateUrl:'template/warrantytpl.php',
        controller:'warrantyController'                     
      } 
    }
```

All these will now start to work:

```
  <a href="#/warranty">
  <a href="#/warranty/2345">
  <a href="#/warranty/5678">

  <a ui-sref="warrantyid">
  <a ui-sref="warrantyid({id:1234})">
  <a ui-sref="warrantyid({id:4567})">
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/L6vAe7ninidWsn57IGPR?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but in my case this is not working, its only working for the url like "warranty" but not working for "warranty/1234".  when I try to hit the url "warranty/1234" its just landing to me "warranty/" and loading the homepage template.

Comment: I would suggest - change my plunker to reproduce the error. I am ready to assist and find solution. In general (as the plunker shows) you must be very close (BTS are you using html5 mode?)

Comment: I am using : `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

Comment: I would expect that... so in this case, you should tweak your SERVER. It is for sure not ready to handle HTML 5 style. CHeck the details  here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode - once this is done, UI-Router will be working as expected (SUMMARY - your server is not configured well, it does try to solve the request, instead of letting it go... )

Comment: I am unable to configure server cause I am not authorized to do that. but I want to ask you one thing that "the method I am trying as I asked in my question, the same method working proper in desktop application but not working in mobile application". So do i need to define specifically for mobile? Because I think when this is working in desktop app then ideally it should work for mobile also.